# what happens in memory when we declare a delegate in c#?

Tags: c#

is delegate a method or class?
if it is a method then how come we can instantiate it?
only class can be instantiated 
so then the delegate must be class
please help me
I'm a bit confused due to this 
and where the delegate is stored in heap or stack?

Comment: It is a class.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: _"where the delegate is stored in heap or stack"_ is the wrong question. Where something is stored has very little to do with what kind of type it is. In particular, value types are stored wherever is appropriate given the context. E.g. value type fields of a reference type are stored in the heap, as are captured value type local variables (after all, they wind up implicitly as a field in a reference type).

Answer (score 2):

A delegate is a reference type, same as a class, and as such is stored on the heap.
Think of a delegate as an "stack" of references, that holds a function/method signatures.

Answer (score 1):

Delegate is a Type Safe Pointer to point to your methods/functions. Which means you can pass the methods/functions as a parameter using delegates and it will be safe with the types also.

For more info check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173171.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) link

Answer (score 0):

A delegate is conceptually a **type**, but it's defined and acts as a class (with a `MethodInfo` property, an instance -or target-, and some methods -and runtime information, etc.-).

It defines a method signature. To instantiate it, you need to associate it with a method (so it's basically syntactic sugar to reference methods with an explicit signature).

It also has an `Invoke` method which is defined by the signature of the `MethodInfo` associated in runtime.

Comment: Looking at the following - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/delegate.cs,f90e13dc7115bc8c I am not sure about the accuracy of this answer. It could certainly be refined IMHO.

Comment: Of course there are implementation details not mentioned, but how is that so different from the answer? From what I see in the reference source code you linked: it's a class, it has a MethodInfo field (a property, ok), a target object, and the compilers have syntactic sugar for it..

Comment: Things which are unclear to me - 1. What is meant by its a type, but defined and acts like a class? 2. Claim that it has a MethodInfo field. 3. not sure what is meant by it has "runtime information" either... or "It defines a method signature".. or "you need to <associate> it with a method". 4. I would certainly not call it a syntactic sugar.. It is not. etc etc...

Comment: It "conceptually" acts as a type (a reference type that defines a method signature), but it's a class. it has a MethodInfo property (called [Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.method(v=vs.110).aspx)). It has runtime information (as all classes in .NET), you need to associate it with a method (hey, even [the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e.aspx) calls it "associate") to instantiate one (which if you could `new` it you'd do it using a constructor, but there's -syntactic sugar- to do it with a lambda or `=`, and even its own keyword).

Comment: I don't know... you might think my answer was not "detailed enough" and I'm definitely no Eric Lippert to give out all implementation details of a delegate (which I frankly, don't know), but I don't think it's fair to say it was not "accurate".

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.. I might be being picky here.. but Please call it a Property and not a field.. MSDN is equally confusing / unclear to me with their use of word "associate".. Concept / use of lambda in C# doesn't make Delegates themselves syntactic sugar. I am trying to provide feedback, certainly not down voting or being harsh I hope.. I understand you are trying to help someone here :) Thanks

Comment: I have edited to change "field" to "property". With syntactic sugar, I mean that, even if it's a class, you don't use it like if it was (it's even abstract because if the implementation is as I suspect, when you define a delegate, it actually creates a dynamic descendant class of `System.Delegate` with the correct `Invoke` method with the described signature). If you were to use it as a class (not with its own syntax), you'd need to actually define that inherited class yourself: it has "sugar" to allow you to do it in an easy way. Maybe the use of "sugar" in my head doesn't match yours

Comment: And don't worry, I don't think you were "harsh", I just stand by my answer and defend it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Delegate is just a type much like a class it allocates memory on the heap and an instance to call it on.and the delegate variable holds reference to this object.

Something like

```
        public class SomeAction : Delegate
        {
              private object _instance;
              private MethodInfo _method;
              public void Invoke()
              {
                //Invoke
              }
          }
```

Not exactly like this but something similar to it